# Is it possible to code Visio's "Create from Data" data visualizer feature with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, visio

Is it possible to code Visio's "Create from Data" feature into VBA? I want the link established between Excel and Visio to be synchronous, just like how the feature itself is.

In Visio, I tried recording a macro that involved using the "Create from Data" feature to make the data visualizer, but it became unavailable while I was recording. I can't find anything online about it.

Comment: What have you tried so far other than creating code with the macro recorder? SO is not a free code writing service. Suggest reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question.

Comment: I'm not asking for the code... I was just asking to see if it's possible, and where I could learn more about it. I am relatively inexperienced with VBA. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need manage diagram which was created with Data Visualizer (IMHO it is impossible) ?     Or want create tool like Data Visualizer (it is possible for simple diagrams)

Comment: I need the code to create cross-functional horizontal flow chart Data Visualizers (like you get with the "Create from Data" button) with the parameters I give it. It needs to have the features that you normally get with the "Create from Data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data visualizer does not currently provide any API. So using it from VBA is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can work out what data you want entered where and which buttons to press on the form then you can use SendKeys to do what you want.